# Choosing which returned value to use

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some example code:

```
function iLoveCheese(){
    return { 
        'c': thenumber, 'd': anothernumber 
    }
}
```

Say I want to use 'thenumber' in a program, can I just do:-

```
function lotsOfCheese(){
    var t = iLoveCheese();
    return t.thenumber;
}
```

Is a correct understanding?

Comment: That is almost correct.  Return t.c;  But something this simple, why did you not just try it and see?  I am putting this as a comment rather than an answer because I would feel silly accepting reputation for something like this.

Comment: No, it is not. I recommend to read: [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: But... `thenumber` is not a key of the returned value...

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the comment, after reading his actual code more carefully.  But the point stands--this would have been easier to test than to ask about, so I feel no shame in giving it short shrift on the read.

Comment: OK, so if I return c, I will get the answer i need? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lotsOfCheese` function is not going to work as excepted. This is because the `ILoveCheese` function returns an **object**. You need to reference this object by it's **keys**, not it's **values**.

```
function lotsOfCheese(){
  var t = iLoveCheese();
  return t.c; // "c" is the key of the object t
}
```

This will return a value, `thenumber`